# EF ToTraceString SQL generation result columns order

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

My question is if I can predict or choose the exact order of the columns the sql generation through `ToTraceString()` returns.

I use `ToTraceString()` for an IQueryable to get the resulted SQL command and then insert the results directly in a database table.

So, I kind of need the generated SQL to be consistent with my table structure...

```
string insertQuery = string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} {1}", sqlTableName ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<TRow>)results).ToTraceString());
Context.ExecuteStoreCommand(string.Format("TRUNCATE TABLE {0}", sqlTableName));
Context.ExecuteStoreCommand(insertQuery);
```

`results = IQueryable<Row>` where Row is a type with the same properties as the table columns

I choose to do a direct insert into a table because i see no point in getting a ToList() enumerable on the webserver, just to send it back to SQL through some kind of bulk insert (which EF doesn;t support for the moment...) My query returns a considerable amount of rows and I do not want to use Stored Procedures.

Hope I make sense...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue but the answer here still required a fair amount of work to get going. I used the part of [How does Entity Framework manage mapping query result to anonymous type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808607/how-does-entity-framework-manage-mapping-query-result-to-anonymous-type) to get the order and returned the names, then a simple parsing to extract the field names.

I made an extension method that pulls everything together:

```
public static string ToWrappedString(this ObjectQuery query, out ObjectParameterCollection parameters)
{
    var trace = query.ToTraceString();
    parameters = query.Parameters;
    var positions = query.GetPropertyPositions();

    // the query should be SELECT\n
    //  Column AS NNN
    //  FROM
    // so we regex this out
    var regex = new Regex("^SELECT(?<columns>.*?)FROM", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    var result = regex.Match(trace.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""));
    var cols = result.Groups["columns"];

    // then we have the columns so split to get each
    const string As = " AS ";
    var colNames = cols.Value.Split(',').Select(a => a.Substring(a.IndexOf(As, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) + As.Length)).ToArray();


    var wrapped = "SELECT " + String.Join(Environment.NewLine + ", ", colNames.Select((a, i) => string.Format("{0}{1} [{2}]", a, As, positions[i]))) + " FROM (" + trace
                  + ") WrappedQuery ";
    return wrapped;
}
```

This is the code from the other link, updated to EF6 internals and returning the name in column order rather than the indexes.

```
public static string[] GetPropertyPositions(this ObjectQuery query)
{
    // get private ObjectQueryState ObjectQuery._state;
    // of actual type internal class
    //      System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState
    object queryState = GetProperty(query, "QueryState");
    AssertNonNullAndOfType(queryState, "System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState");

    // get protected ObjectQueryExecutionPlan ObjectQueryState._cachedPlan;
    // of actual type internal sealed class
    //      System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan
    object plan = GetField(queryState, "_cachedPlan");
    AssertNonNullAndOfType(plan, "System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan");

    // get internal readonly DbCommandDefinition ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.CommandDefinition;
    // of actual type internal sealed class
    //      System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition
    object commandDefinition = GetField(plan, "CommandDefinition");
    AssertNonNullAndOfType(commandDefinition, "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition");

    // get private readonly IColumnMapGenerator EntityCommandDefinition._columnMapGenerator;
    // of actual type private sealed class
    //      System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ConstantColumnMapGenerator
    var columnMapGeneratorArray = GetField(commandDefinition, "_columnMapGenerators") as object[];
    AssertNonNullAndOfType(columnMapGeneratorArray, "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition+IColumnMapGenerator[]");

    var columnMapGenerator = columnMapGeneratorArray[0];

    // get private readonly ColumnMap ConstantColumnMapGenerator._columnMap;
    // of actual type internal class
    //      System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.SimpleCollectionColumnMap
    object columnMap = GetField(columnMapGenerator, "_columnMap");
    AssertNonNullAndOfType(columnMap, "System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.SimpleCollectionColumnMap");

    // get internal ColumnMap CollectionColumnMap.Element;
    // of actual type internal class
    //      System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RecordColumnMap
    object columnMapElement = GetProperty(columnMap, "Element");
    AssertNonNullAndOfType(columnMapElement, "System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RecordColumnMap");

    // get internal ColumnMap[] StructuredColumnMap.Properties;
    // array of internal abstract class
    //      System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMap
    Array columnMapProperties = GetProperty(columnMapElement, "Properties") as Array;
    AssertNonNullAndOfType(columnMapProperties, "System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMap[]");

    int n = columnMapProperties.Length;
    string[] propertyPositions = new string[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        // get value at index i in array
        // of actual type internal class
        //      System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ScalarColumnMap
        object column = columnMapProperties.GetValue(i);
        AssertNonNullAndOfType(column, "System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScalarColumnMap");

        string colName = (string)GetProperty(column, "Name");
        // can be used for more advanced bingings

        // get internal int ScalarColumnMap.ColumnPos;
        object columnPositionOfAProperty = GetProperty(column, "ColumnPos");
        AssertNonNullAndOfType(columnPositionOfAProperty, "System.Int32");

        propertyPositions[(int)columnPositionOfAProperty] = colName;
    }
    return propertyPositions;
}

static object GetProperty(object obj, string propName)
{
    PropertyInfo prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (prop == null) throw EFChangedException();
    return prop.GetValue(obj, new object[0]);
}

static object GetField(object obj, string fieldName)
{
    FieldInfo field = obj.GetType().GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (field == null) throw EFChangedException();
    return field.GetValue(obj);
}

static void AssertNonNullAndOfType(object obj, string fullName)
{
    if (obj == null) throw EFChangedException();
    string typeFullName = obj.GetType().FullName;
    if (typeFullName != fullName) throw EFChangedException();
}

static InvalidOperationException EFChangedException()
{
    return new InvalidOperationException("Entity Framework internals has changed, please review and fix reflection code");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073001/where-does-entity-framework-store-the-mapping-between-property-names-and-the-col) contains two links which describe how to figure out what order the various properties of the entity type appear in the SQL generated by ToTraceString(). With that information, you can do some simple parsing/restructuring of the raw SQL to replace the weird column names EF uses (e. g. C1, C2, etc) with the property column names. Then, you could wrap the generated SQL in a subquery that selects the relevant columns in the order you want:

```
SELECT prop1, prop2
FROM
(
    // the result of ToTraceString(), with EF's generated column names replaced by the property names of the query type
) x
```