# Where does Entity Framework store the mapping between property names and the columns it selects in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to build some custom extensions onto EF (4.3) using ObjectQuery's ToTraceString() to generate raw SQL from LINQ code.

I've noticed that while in some cases the names of the columns in SQL match the property names of the query's element type, in other cases they are named things like C1, C2, etc. This makes it very difficult for me to do anything with the generated SQL. Does anyone know how to map these column names back to property names (I only care about being able to do this for flat tuples such as anonymous types if that helps, I don't need anything hierarchical).

A solution that relies on private/internal reflection is perfectly acceptable. I understand that I may have to adjust it with future EF releases. Also, I am only using MS SqlServer (2008+) if it helps.

Comment: That would require you to go directly to query generation process and not only using `ToTraceString`.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: can you explain this? It seems that this mapping information must be available after ToTraceString() because the ObjectQuery is able to materialize the result objects after emitting the raw SQL. For example, I am currently able to do the following: (1) generate SQL with ToTraceString() (2) modify it and execute it (3) translate the returned DataReader back to objects using the internal QueryState object in the ObjectQuery.

Comment: You are able to translate only result set where columns match mapping of your entities.

Comment: EF assigns names like this to calculated columns (e.g. a `CASE WHEN` column, or just `SELECT ..., 1 AS [C1]`), so often it is not possible to resolve them back to one original column name.

Comment: @GertArnold it must be possible, since EF does it. I'm not saying that you can do this by looking at the column names alone. Instead, I assume the the ObjectQuery has some sort of internal state that does this.

Comment: @Chasemedallion You're absolutely right...the ObjectQuery does indeed store the mapping and you'll have to get into the ObjectQuery's internals in order to extract this information.  Please see my answer for how this can be accomplished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just asked and answered a similar question (you can ignore all the DataTable stuff, but it might be useful in that it shows how the mapping is used):

[Entity Framework - IQueryable to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083740/entity-framework-iqueryable-to-datatable)

The original post that shows how to get at the mapping between the object property positions and SQL statement column positions can be found here:

[How does Entity Framework manage mapping query result to anonymous type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808607/how-does-entity-framework-manage-mapping-query-result-to-anonymous-type)

**Note:** The second link only provides a mapping of the **positions** (as integer values) between the object properties and the SQL statement columns...you'll have to use reflection to get at the actual object property names and then do some kind of string analysis on the SQL statement to get the SQL statement column names (you could use regular expressions for this, but that might be overkill).