# entity framework column name to property mapping dbentry

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to map entity properties to database column names while saving entities in DbContext, but I can't figure how to do it in EF7.

After generating database schema with migrations, column names are not always the same as properties names in object. 
For example, below object schema:

```
public class Document
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public User Author { get; set; }
}
```

would have *Id*, *Name* and ***AuthorId*** columns in database.
Next when I'm iterating over EntityEntry properties, it contains Id, Name and AthorId columns. I can easily map Id and Name. 
Thing I'm looking for is how to figure out that "AuthorId" in EntityEntry is mapped to Author field in Document?

**Backround**: I'm implementing universal object version history mechanism, which would get modified columns from EntityEntries (from *ChangeTracker* in *SaveChanges*() in *DbContext*) and save proper columns and it new values. Next, when restoring objects it should be able to map these changes to proper entity fields.

I have found similar question for EF6 [Where does Entity Framework store the mapping between property names and the columns it selects in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073001/where-does-entity-framework-store-the-mapping-between-property-names-and-the-col) but it is quite complicated and uses classes specific to EF6.

Comment: The `Author` field is not a simple object/primitive and as such is treated as a navigation property (IE: The ID of an object that exists in another table). By default EF7 will add "Id" to the name of the navigational property and store that as an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, the `Author` field is not a simple object/struct (IE: `DateTime`, `Enum`, etc) nor a primitive (IE: `int`, `string`, etc). As such, it is a `Navigation Property` and only the ID of the object is stored. This ID then allows you to **navigate** to the row in another table that stores the complex data of the `Author` object.

As such, you would want a `DbContext` and `DbSet`s as such:

```
public class Document {
    public int Id { get; set; } // No need for [Key] ID is auto detected
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Foreign Keys
    public int AuthorId { get; set; } // Can use "int?" if you want to allow it to be nullable
    public User Author { get; set; }
}

public class Author {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BookContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

This will produce tables:

```
Document: Id (int), Name (nvarchar), AuthorId (int) with FK to Author table
Author:   Id (int), Name (nvarchar)
```

When querying the DB:

```
var books = BookContext.Documents // Access documents table
                 .Include(q => q.Author) // Ensure that the author's properties are loaded, not just the ID
                 .Where(q => q.Name.Contains("SomeText")) // Search for documents with a name matching this text
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This (in some way) solves problem with FK  properties but I'm still looking for solution for getting mentioned mapping.

Comment: @Tomqaz, you can't really, the db only knows about the fk and the id, everything else is handled by ef. You do know however, that navigation property + "Id" will be the id key (especially if you set your tables up like I have shown). You could look in the information schema table and lookup the fk (IE: if fk exists you know it's a navigation property), this might help?

Comment: @Tomqaz, I should also note, the navigation property is tracked by change tracker (IE: if you change authors). I recently developed a similar ef7 history tracker, and I iterated through the entities properties where old value != current value. There are a number of questions on this site detailing as such.

Comment: Ok, maybe this will be enough. Thx one more time =]