# Entity Framework - IQueryable to DataTable

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, datatable, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I'm trying to convert an `IQueryable` object to a `DataTable`.  Here's an example of a query that I would like to convert to a `DataTable`:

```
var query = DbContext.SomeObjectSet.Select(x => new { PropertyName1 = x.ColumnName1, PropertyName2 = x.ColumnName2 });
```

Please note the anonymous object that is created in the `Select` method and the names of the properties:

```
new { PropertyName1 = x.ColumnName1, PropertyName2 = x.ColumnName2 }
```

After Googling this issue, I came across the following code that converts an `IQueryable` object to a `DataTable`:

```
public static DataTable EntityToDatatable(this IQueryable result)
{
    ObjectQuery query = (result as ObjectQuery);

    ObjectContext context = query.Context;

    EntityConnection entityCon = (context.Connection as EntityConnection);

    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(entityCon.StoreConnection.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query.ToTraceString(), sqlCon))
        {
            foreach (var param in query.Parameters)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(param.Name, param.Value);

            }

            using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                using (DataTable dataTable = new DataTable())
                {
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

                    return dataTable;

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

The code above "works" and the SQL statement from the `ToTraceString()` method is as follows:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[ColumnName1] AS [ColumnName1], [Extent1].[ColumnName2] AS [ColumnName2] FROM [dbo].[TableName] AS [Extent1]
```

**Problem:** The column names of the SQL statement (i.e. `columnName1` and `columnName2`) do not correspond to the names of the properties of the objects (i.e. `PropertyName1` and `PropertyName2`) that would be materialized if a `ToList()` or `AsEnumerable()` method was called on the `query`. This wouldn't be so bad if the SQL statement columns were in the same order as the anonymous object properties...but, **this is not always the case**.  Somewhere (I guess inside of the IQueryable object) there must be a mapping between the SQL statement column names and the resulting anonymous object property names.

Does anyone know how to get at this mapping?

Comment: Why would you want to store the results in a `DataTable`?

Comment: @Eranga Good question!  Well, for most intents and purposes converting an IQueryable object to a DataTable is pointless.  However, I have created a pivot class which pivots DataTables.  I have already created a pivot class that works on IEnumerables, but it relies quite heavily on reflection. I think that I can get better performance using datatables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution to my problem:

First, you need the following code (from [How does Entity Framework manage mapping query result to anonymous type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808607/how-does-entity-framework-manage-mapping-query-result-to-anonymous-type?rq=1)) which maps the positions of my anonymous object properties to the SQL statement column position:

```
public static Int32[] GetPropertyPositions(this ObjectQuery query)
{
    // get private ObjectQueryState ObjectQuery._state; 
    // of actual type internal class 
    //      System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState 

    Object queryState = GetProperty(query, "QueryState");
    AssertNonNullAndOfType(queryState, "System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState");

    // get protected ObjectQueryExecutionPlan ObjectQueryState._cachedPlan; 
    // of actual type internal sealed class 
    //      System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan 
    Object plan = GetField(queryState, "_cachedPlan");
    AssertNonNullAndOfType(plan, "System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan");

    // get internal readonly DbCommandDefinition ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.CommandDefinition; 
    // of actual type internal sealed class 
    //      System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition 
    Object commandDefinition = GetField(plan, "CommandDefinition");
    AssertNonNullAndOfType(commandDefinition, "System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition");

    // get private readonly IColumnMapGenerator EntityCommandDefinition._columnMapGenerator; 
    // of actual type private sealed class 
    //      System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ConstantColumnMapGenerator 
    Object columnMapGenerator = GetField(commandDefinition, "_columnMapGenerator");
    AssertNonNullAndOfType(columnMapGenerator, "System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition+ConstantColumnMapGenerator");

    // get private readonly ColumnMap ConstantColumnMapGenerator._columnMap; 
    // of actual type internal class 
    //      System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.SimpleCollectionColumnMap 
    Object columnMap = GetField(columnMapGenerator, "_columnMap");
    AssertNonNullAndOfType(columnMap, "System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.SimpleCollectionColumnMap");

    // get internal ColumnMap CollectionColumnMap.Element; 
    // of actual type internal class 
    //      System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RecordColumnMap 
    Object columnMapElement = GetProperty(columnMap, "Element");
    AssertNonNullAndOfType(columnMapElement, "System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RecordColumnMap");

    // get internal ColumnMap[] StructuredColumnMap.Properties; 
    // array of internal abstract class 
    //      System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMap 
    Array columnMapProperties = GetProperty(columnMapElement, "Properties") as Array;
    AssertNonNullAndOfType(columnMapProperties, "System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMap[]");

    Int32 n = columnMapProperties.Length;

    Int32[] propertyPositions = new Int32[n];

    for (Int32 i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        // get value at index i in array 
        // of actual type internal class 
        //      System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ScalarColumnMap 
        Object column = columnMapProperties.GetValue(i);
        AssertNonNullAndOfType(column, "System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ScalarColumnMap");

        //string colName = (string)GetProp(column, "Name"); 
        // can be used for more advanced bingings 

        // get internal int ScalarColumnMap.ColumnPos; 
        Object columnPositionOfAProperty = GetProperty(column, "ColumnPos");
        AssertNonNullAndOfType(columnPositionOfAProperty, "System.Int32");

        propertyPositions[i] = (int)columnPositionOfAProperty;

    }

    return propertyPositions;

}

static object GetProperty(object obj, string propName)
{
    PropertyInfo prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (prop == null) throw EFChangedException();
    return prop.GetValue(obj, new object[0]);

}

static object GetField(object obj, string fieldName)
{
    FieldInfo field = obj.GetType().GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (field == null) throw EFChangedException();
    return field.GetValue(obj);

}

static void AssertNonNullAndOfType(object obj, string fullName)
{
    if (obj == null) throw EFChangedException();
    string typeFullName = obj.GetType().FullName;
    if (typeFullName != fullName) throw EFChangedException();

}

static InvalidOperationException EFChangedException()
{
    return new InvalidOperationException("Entity Framework internals has changed, please review and fix reflection code");

}
```

Then I can modify the `EntityToDatatable` method as follows:

```
public static DataTable EntityToDatatable(this IQueryable query)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = null;
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = null;
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = null;
    DataTable dataTable = null;

    try
    {
        ObjectQuery objectQuery = (query as ObjectQuery);

        ObjectContext objectContext = objectQuery.Context;

        EntityConnection entityConnection = (objectContext.Connection as EntityConnection);

        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(entityConnection.StoreConnection.ConnectionString);

        sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(objectQuery.ToTraceString(), sqlConnection);

        foreach (var parameter in objectQuery.Parameters)
        {
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Name, parameter.Value);

        }

        sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);

        dataTable = new DataTable();

        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

        // Get the mapping between the object property position and 
        // the SQL statment column position.
        Int32[] propertyPositions = objectQuery.GetPropertyPositions();

        // Create a column name to column position (ordinal) lookup.
        Dictionary<String, Int32> mapColumnNameToColumnPosition = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        // Populate the lookup.
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < propertyPositions.Length; ++i)
        {
            mapColumnNameToColumnPosition.Add(dataTable.Columns[propertyPositions[i]].ColumnName, i);

        }

        // Get the object's property information.
        PropertyInfo[] pi = query.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperties();

        // Iterate through the lookup and change the position of the datatable columns.
        // The order of the datatable columns will now correspond to the order of the object
        // properties.
        foreach (var map in mapColumnNameToColumnPosition)
        {
            // Change the column position.
            dataTable.Columns[map.Key].SetOrdinal(map.Value);

            // Change the column name.
            dataTable.Columns[map.Key].ColumnName = pi[map.Value].Name;

        }

        return dataTable;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Something went wrong and we're going to raise an exception...we
        // might as well dispose of the datatable if it exists because it's
        // not going to be used.
        if (dataTable != null) dataTable.Dispose();

        throw new Exception("IQueryable to DataTable conversion error.", ex);

    }
    finally
    {
        // Do some cleanup on objects that are no longer needed.

        if (sqlDataAdapter != null) sqlDataAdapter.Dispose();

        if (sqlCommand != null) sqlCommand.Dispose();

        if (sqlConnection != null) sqlConnection.Dispose();

    }

}
```